# Office Online Server Integration - Get Thumbnails

Tags: sharepoint-server, office-web-apps, thumbnail

is it possible to get thumbnails images from an office online server (or office web app server) for files from a network drive as it provides thumbnail images from sharepoint?

Thumbnail URL from Sharepoint: 
https://test-sharepoint/_layouts/15/WopiFrame.aspx?sourcedoc=testdoc%20CL%2Edocx&action=imagepreview

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately not. The reason you have a thumbnail in SharePoint is that you have exchanged trust between Office Online Server and SharePoint Server. To the best of my knowledge, you can't exchange trust the same way with a Fileshare. And the fileshare doesn't use an IIS website.

More to read: [Configure server-to-server authentication between Office Online Server and SharePoint Server 2016](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt346470(v=office.16).aspx)